# Using a function to return a value in VBA without using the worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon One and All,

I am relatively new to VBA and I am trying to use the Worksheet function, specifically the index function to look up information in the code and bring back a value. I would love to do this without having to assign it to a cell in the worksheet using R1C1. Is there a way to do Vlookups, or Indexex without having to make assignments in the worksheet?
The examples below works as an equation placed within the sheet, but I'd like to get the same answer without having to use the sheet. 
The first formula looks up a Batch number 
The second formula is finding the name of the first ingredient in the batch, based on the SKU in the worksheet.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'U:\Files\Maintenance File.xls'!SKUinfo,16,FALSE)"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=INDEX('U:\Files\[Recipe File.xlsx]Fresh 2800'!Fresh2800,2,6)*(INDEX(SchedInfo,MATCH(RC[-3],SKULookup,0),6))"
```

Any help would be appreciated, and thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to [this Microsoft forum post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/how-to-use-vlookup-in-vba/b1c20dae-b3c5-4679-84bd-4b163a6456e1) describes what you want. Use the [Application object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
ans = Application.VLookup(arg1, MyRange, arg3, arg4)
```